# Connect webcam to google colab

Tags: python, image-processing, google-colaboratory, yolo, yolov5

How can I use my webcam in colab?
I need it for yolov5 running, I want to use the output of webcam as a source for object detection.
`python detect.py --weights yolov5s.pt --source

I have done it with just simply showing the result of webcam in a single code but as I provided I need to use it as an output and combine it with yolov5

When I use the 0 in `python detect.py --weights yolov5s.pt --source 0`
I expect it open my laptops webcam but it doesn't

Comment: source 1 instead of source 0

Comment: @toyotaSupra I tried but no results

Comment: Is your laptop come with built-in webcam?

Comment: @toyotaSupra yes it is

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try adding parameter  `camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)`

Comment: @toyotaSupra where I should use it? before detect.py?

Comment: @Community here is codes I have used: `python detect.py --source 0  # webcam
                          img.jpg  # image
                          vid.mp4  # video
                          screen  # screenshot
                          path/  # directory
                         'path/*.jpg'  # glob
                         'https://youtu.be/LNwODJXcvt4'  # YouTube
                         'rtsp://example.com/media.mp4'  # RTSP, RTMP, HTTP stream`